# Splitting up a column into multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that outputs on a very simple level:

```
Name
Workplace
And a abstract
```

This then repeats over and over. So:

```
NameA
WorkplaceA
And a abstractA
NameB
WorkplaceB
And a abstractB
etc...
```

I need to split this up into three columns:

```
NameCol  WorkplaceCol  AbstractCol

NameA    WorkplaceA    AbstractA
NameB    WorkplaceB    AbstractB
NameC    WorkplaceC    AbstractC
etc...
```

My code loops back to the start when it finds a `<h1>` tag. However, I do not display this tag. So one record is the name, workplace and abstract until it comes across a new `<h1>` tag.

Here is the code I have:

```
headernum = 0
i = 0
x = soup.find_all("h1")

for i in range(len(x)):
    header = soup.find_all('h1')[headernum]
    name = header.find_all_next('p')[1]
    print(name.text)
    workplace = name.find_all_next('i')[0]
    print(workplace.text)
    abstract = []
    for elem in name.next_siblings:
        if elem.name == 'h1':
            break
        if elem.name != 'p':
            continue
        abstract.append(elem.get_text())
    x = " ".join(abstract).replace("\n", " ").encode('utf-8')
    print(x)
    i += 1
    headernum += 1
```

I am struggling to split this up and put columns in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a df like that :

```
col1
NameA
WorkplaceA
AbstractA
NameB
WorkplaceB
AbstractB
```

You can do :

```
import numpy as np

# Set the same number for each 3 lines
df['index'] = df.index / 3
df['index'] = df['index'].apply(np.floor)

# Set 0 for Names, 1 for Workplaces and 2 for Abstract
df["type_id"] = df.index % 3

# Rename 0, 1 and 2 by a label
df["type_label"] = df["type_id"].map({0: "Name", 1: "Workplace", 2: "Abstract"})

# Pivot the table
df = df.pivot(index='index', columns='type_label', values='col1')
print(df)
```

It will give you :

```
type_label   Abstract   Name   Workplace
index
0.0         AbstractA  NameA  WorkplaceA
1.0         AbstractB  NameB  WorkplaceB
```

Comment: This idea for this solution is OK. You are missing the requirement to block *h1 tags*. Besides that, the order of columns is not right and you can use `df['index'] = df.index // 3` for the integer division without needing to import numpy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process your own input format, you need to make
some assumptions. For this code example, I assume that "h1" appears between sets of three lines. If it's allowed in the middle, the code needs to be slightly different.

The idea:

- Write a generator function, that loops through the text and returns each full row in dictionary form.
- Collect them all
- As you marked your question "pandas", move the result into a pandas dataframe

Here is a working example.

```
import pandas as pd

example_text="""NameA
WorkplaceA
And a abstractA
NameB
WorkplaceB
And a abstractB
<h1>
NameC
WorkplaceC
And a abstractC"""

def next_name(mystr):
    lines = iter(mystr.split('\n'))
    while True:
        n = {'NameCol':None,
         'WorkplaceCol':None,
         'AbstractCol':None
        }
        try:
            n['NameCol'] = next(lines)
            if n['NameCol'] == '<h1>':
                continue
            n['WorkplaceCol'] = next(lines)
            if n['WorkplaceCol'] == '<h1>':
                continue
            n['AbstractCol'] = next(lines)
            if n['AbstractCol'] == '<h1>':
                continue
            yield n 
        except StopIteration:
            break

df = pd.DataFrame(next_name(example_text), columns=['NameCol','WorkplaceCol','AbstractCol'])
print(df)
```

The dataframe prints as

```
  NameCol WorkplaceCol      AbstractCol
0   NameA   WorkplaceA  And a abstractA
1   NameB   WorkplaceB  And a abstractB
2   NameC   WorkplaceC  And a abstractC
```

If you need to print the dataframe exactly as your example,
here's example code.

```
print(''.join(f'{x}\t' for x in df.columns))
print()
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(''.join(f'{x}\t' for x in row[1]))
```

Output

```
NameCol WorkplaceCol    AbstractCol 

NameA   WorkplaceA  And a abstractA 
NameB   WorkplaceB  And a abstractB 
NameC   WorkplaceC  And a abstractC
```

Note: I'm using Python 3.6, if your are using an older version, you need to change the print command.

In comparison, doing it with Pandas can look like this (using the example from the code above)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_text.split('\n'))
df = df[df[0] != '<h1>'].reset_index().copy()
df['row'] = df.index // 3
result = df.groupby('row').agg(lambda x: list(x))[0].values

print('\t'.join(["NameCol", "WorkplaceCol", "AbstractCol"]))
print('')
print('\n'.join(['\t'.join(x) for x in result]))
```

Which outputs the same.

```
NameCol WorkplaceCol    AbstractCol

NameA   WorkplaceA  And a abstractA
NameB   WorkplaceB  And a abstractB
NameC   WorkplaceC  And a abstractC
```